# How to add arrow glyphs to a Bootstrap-style collapsible panel in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I need to implement a Bootstrap-style collapsible panel in React that displays arrow glyphs in the panel header similar to this [No JS required](https://codepen.io/tofanelli/pen/waadRY/)  example.

I've implemented most of this functionality using react-bootstrap in an unintended way, that results in this browser warning:

> < a> cannot appear as a descendant of < a>. See ProjectInfo > a > ... > Panel > a.

Here is the render function of my component:

```
render() {
     const projectHeader =
        <a className="accordion-toggle collapsed">
            <h4 className="panel-title">Project Information</h4>
        </a>;
    return (
        <Accordion>
            <Panel header={projectHeader} eventKey="1">
                Project info goes here.
            </Panel>
        </Accordion>
    );
}
```

Can the requirement for toggling panel header icons be be met using react-bootstrap? If so, how? If not, how is it done using React?

UPDATED 07-DEC-2017: I solved my problem by adding an anchorClass property to the react-bootstrap Panel component in a [forked repo](https://github.com/whartonlearninglab/react-bootstrap).

This is final render function of my component:

```
render() {
    const header = <h4>Project Information</h4>;
    return (
        <PanelGroup accordion>
            <Panel header={header} anchorClass="panel-toggle" eventKey="1">
                Project info goes here.
            </Panel>
        </PanelGroup>
    );
}
```

The panel-toggle classes were defined like those in the No JS required example.

Comment: I think that you get that warning because you are inserting <a> component (projectHeader) through props to <Panel /> ... But panel already uses <a> inside, and puts your projctHeader component inside his <a>. And that is why you get that warning.

Comment: Yes, but it works -- a clickable arrow icon appears in the correct location. Is there a better way to achieve the same result?